# MakeFile undefined reference to Test

Tags: makefile

```
PRODUCT=Main

CPPFLAGS=-Iproduct -Itest -Istacks_cpp/product -Iqueue_cpp/product
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -ggdb -O0 $(CPPFLAGS)

SOURCES=$(wildcard product/*.cpp) \
        $(wildcard test/*.cpp)  \
        $(wildcard stacks_cpp/product/*.cpp)    \
        $(wildcard queue_cpp/product/*.cpp)

HEADERS=$(wildcard product/*.h) \
        $(wildcard test/*.h)    \
        $(wildcard stacks_cpp/product/*.h)  \
        $(wildcard queue_cpp/product/*.h)

LDFLAGS=-lgtest -lgmock -lgmock_main -lpthread

CXX=g++

.PHONY: all clean test

all: $(PRODUCT)

$(PRODUCT): $(SOURCES) $(HEADERS)
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(SOURCES) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
    @rm -rf $(PRODUCT)
    @rm -rf kwinject.out .kwlp .kwps

klocwork:
    @kwcheck run

klocwork_after_makefile_change: clean
    @/opt/klocwork/kwenv.sh
    @kwcheck run

test: $(PRODUCT)
    @./$(PRODUCT)
```

So this is the contents of my MakeFile and I get an undefined reference when I make.
the error is in this line.

```c
@$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(SOURCES) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
```

I don't know how to configure the MakeFile but what I want is that I have a folder that has 2 code folder with a MakeFile. These 2 folder share the same MakeFile. I put their paths in the `wildcards` and added `-Istacks_cpp/product` and `-Istacks_cpp/product` everything else was default.

The original path of the MakeFile was inside the `stacks_cpp` and I just moved it so it can `make` 2 files for me.

edit:
The error output that I am getting is

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/libgmock.so: undefined reference to `testing::internal::GetCurrentOsStackTraceExceptTop[abi:cxx11](testing::UnitTest*, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/libgmock.so: undefined reference to `testing::internal::GTestLog::GTestLog(testing::internal::GTestLogSeverity, char const*, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/libgmock_main.so: undefined reference to `testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/libgmock.so: undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/libgmock.so: undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/libgmock.so: undefined reference to `testing::internal::IsTrue(bool)'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/libgmock.so: undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/libgmock.so: undefined reference to `testing::internal::AssertHelper::operator=(testing::Message const&) const'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/libgmock.so: undefined reference to `testing::Message::Message()'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/libgmock.so: undefined reference to `testing::InitGoogleTest(int*, wchar_t**)'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/libgmock.so: undefined reference to `testing::internal::AssertHelper::~AssertHelper()'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/libgmock.so: undefined reference to `testing::internal::g_linked_ptr_mutex'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/libgmock.so: undefined reference to `testing::Message::GetString[abi:cxx11]() const'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/libgmock.so: undefined reference to `testing::UnitTest::current_test_info() const'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/libgmock.so: undefined reference to `testing::internal::PrintStringTo(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::ostream*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/libgmock_main.so: undefined reference to `testing::UnitTest::Run()'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/libgmock.so: undefined reference to `testing::internal::GTestLog::~GTestLog()'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/libgmock.so: undefined reference to `testing::internal::FormatFileLocation[abi:cxx11](char const*, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/libgmock.so: undefined reference to `testing::Message::operator<<(wchar_t*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/libgmock.so: undefined reference to `testing::internal::AssertHelper::AssertHelper(testing::TestPartResult::Type, char const*, int, char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/libgmock.so: undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/libgmock.so: undefined reference to `testing::InitGoogleTest(int*, char**)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:25: Main] Error 1
```

Comment: This is a very bizarre makefile.  Basically, whenever any source or header file changes you are recompiling every source file and linking it together.  It doesn't seem useful to even _have_ a makefile here; you might as well just have a shell script that runs the single command line.

Comment: However, there's nothing obviously wrong here that I can see that would cause your problem.  So, it must be related to something you didn't show us.  What is the undefined reference?  Which file do you think should define that symbol?  Does that file appear on the compile line that make shows you?  You will have to show us more information if you need more help.

Comment: Put option `-pthread` into your `CXXFLAGS`, and remove `-lpthread` from your `LDFLAGS`.  Also, the order of command-line options is significant to the linker.  Try moving `-lgtest` to the end of the remaining `LDFLAGS`.

Comment: ok I got less error now. the errors im getting is with `pthread`. edit I typed `lpthread` instead. I think its working now. I get 0 test case but I think the problem is the `wildcard` path now.